# Не выводится число из настроек в SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

Пишу лабораторную работу по Android. Нужно создать программку, которая хранит настройки аккаунта. Сохранение и восстановление настроек должно происходить в функциях onPause и onResume с помощью класса Preferences.

Я сделала 3 поля. 2 поля (name и parol) это настройки, которые записываются в виде строки, а третья настройка с названием identf это число. Все настройки, нормально сохраняются с помощью функции saveName, но при выводе этих же настроек на экран с помощью функции getname, приложение завершает работу. Ошибка идет именно в выводе числа.
Компилятор выдает ошибку на эти 2 строки. Помогите разобраться в чем причина.

```
Integer identf = settings.getInt(PREF_IDENTF, 0);
        identfView.setText(identf);
```

Ниже привожу полный код.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.a1.lab_3_1.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Введите логин"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Введите пароль"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/identfBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Введите идентификатор"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Сохранить"
            android:onClick="saveName"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/passwordView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/identfView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Получить имя"
            android:onClick="getName"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

package com.example.a1.lab_3_1;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String PREFS_FILE = "account";
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "name";
    private static final String PREF_PAROL = "parol";
    private static final String PREF_IDENTF = "identf";
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public void saveName(View view) {
        // получаем введенное имя
        EditText nameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameBox);
        String name = nameBox.getText().toString();

        EditText passwordBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordBox);
        String parol = passwordBox.getText().toString();

        EditText identfBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.identfBox);
        Integer identf = Integer.parseInt (identfBox.getText().toString());
        // сохраняем его в настройках
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
        prefEditor.putString(PREF_NAME, name);
        prefEditor.putString(PREF_PAROL, parol);
        prefEditor.putInt(PREF_IDENTF, identf);
        prefEditor.apply();
    }

    public void getName(View view) {
        // получаем сохраненное имя
        TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        String name = settings.getString(PREF_NAME,"не определено");
        nameView.setText(name);

        TextView passwordView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passwordView);
        String parol = settings.getString(PREF_PAROL,"не определено");
        passwordView.setText(parol);

        TextView identfView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.identfView);
        Integer identf = settings.getInt(PREF_IDENTF, 0);
        identfView.setText(identf);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        EditText nameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameBox);
        String name = nameBox.getText().toString();

        EditText passwordBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordBox);
        String parol = passwordBox.getText().toString();

        EditText identfBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.identfBox);
        Integer identf = Integer.parseInt (identfBox.getText().toString());
        // сохраняем в настройках
        prefEditor = settings.edit();
        prefEditor.putString(PREF_NAME, nameBox.getText().toString());
        prefEditor.putString(PREF_PAROL, passwordBox.getText().toString());
        prefEditor.putInt(PREF_IDENTF, identf);
        prefEditor.apply();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если метод `setText()` получает в качестве аргумента целое число, то он считает это число идентификатором строки из ресурса (как `R.string.text`).
Хотя вы хотели получить совсем другое, с точки зрения компилятора для вашего числа не нашлось подходящего идентификатора строки и он выдает ошибку о его отсутствии.

Для того, чтобы вывести число через метод `setText` его сначала необходимо преобразовать в строку любым доступным способом, например:

```
identfView.setText(Integer.toString(identf));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.