# Почему крашится?

Tags: android, android-studio

Без строчки `click.setText(clicks);` все запускается, но и смысла нет тогда.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    click = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}
public void Onclick(View view) {
    int clicks = 50;
    clicks--;
    click.setText(clicks);
}
```

}

Comment: замените на `click.setText(""+clicks);`, тем самым дав понять, что хотите использовать конструктор, принимающий в качестве параметра строку.

Comment: спасибо,но засчитывается только 1 клик, остальные нажатия не отнимаются, в чем еще проблема?

Comment: в том что `int clicks = 50;` надо вынести за пределы метода.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/911512/177345

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае, вы определяете переменную `clicks` при каждом вызове метода `Onclick` и присваиваете ему значение 50, затем уменьшаете его и присваиваете все время значение 49 для `EditText`. Для вашей цели необходимо переменную `clicks` сделать либо глобальной (что не совсем правильно), либо приватным полем активити/фрагмента/класса ("глобальное" в пределах класса), инициализировать его в `onCreate` значением 50, а в `Onclick` уменьшать и присваивать его значение `EditText`.

По поводу ошибки d `click.setText(clicks);`: так как `clicks` является `int` то используется перегруженный метод `setText(int resId)`, в параметр которого необходимо передать идентификатор строкового ресурса из `strings.xml`, и там нет строки с идентификатором "49". Необходимо `int` преобразовать в `String`

```
private int clicks;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    click = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    clicks = 50;
}
public void Onclick(View view) {
    clicks--;
    click.setText(String.valueOf(clicks));
}
```